# log was unexpected at this time (batch script)

Tags: oracle, batch-file

```
@echo off
set result_file=result.log
set user_name=myName
set password=myPassword
set net_service_name=myService

if exists %result_file% (
   del %result_file%
)
echo @sample1.sql
echo exit
) | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name% >> %result_file%

pause
```

This is my script in .bat, I am trying to connect to my oracle db and I am getting error "result.log was unexpected at this time" in the command prompt.

The sample1.sql is just a normal select * from table statement.

Comment: It's `if exist`, not `if exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exists` should be `exist` (`del %result_file% 2>nul` is equivalent - delete the file and don't complain if it doesn't exist)

The `)` appears orphaned. Perhaps there should be a matching `(` somewhere....